# How to do "on delete row from `user`, delete all from `message` with that username"? FK or trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `user` which has a 'username'.

I have another table called `message` which has messages between 'sender_username' and 'recipient_username'.

I'm trying to have it so that if I delete a user from `user`, all messages associated with them are deleted as well.

I've been reading about FK ON DELETE CASCADE and trigger. Not sure what they do exactly and which is most appropriate for this situation.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `FOREIGN_KEY` is the best solution in this case. If you delete user from `users` table all entries from `message` table related with the deleted user will be removed automatically.

Read this: [Foreign Key Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) - its well explained.